# How can I aggregate close time events in R

Tags: r

I need to be able a data frame with events, and output the start, end and count of runs, where runs are where the events are less than a specified time period together.

The data.frame rows are already sorted by time

e.g.

```
library(lubridate)

ts <- c("2016-10-28 19:21:19",
        "2016-10-28 19:21:20",
        "2016-10-28 19:21:21",
        "2016-10-28 19:21:21",
        "2016-10-28 19:23:23",
        "2016-10-28 19:23:24",
        "2016-10-28 19:23:24",
        "2016-10-28 19:23:25",
        "2016-10-30 03:59:09",
        "2016-10-30 08:54:31",
        "2016-10-30 08:54:35"
)

df  <- data.frame(time=ymd_hms(ts))
```

What I would like outputted is a data frame like this, where the interval is 60s from the previous event

```
start                end                  count
2016-10-28 19:21:19  2016-10-28 19:21:21  4 
2016-10-28 19:23:23  2016-10-28 19:23:25  4
2016-10-30 03:59:09  2016-10-30 03:59:09  1
2016-10-30 08:54:31  2016-10-30 08:54:35  2
```

The actual sequences would be very long, so the solution would need to perform well with a lot (~100k) rows

I've looked at `lag`, `diff`and other functions, but cannot see an easy or efficient way of doing this.

Comment: What is an event and what is the logic for the counts? `2016-10-28 19:21:19` is closer to `2016-10-28 19:21:20`   . . . .

Comment: An event in this example is an instance of an error, and I am looking to report on 'clusters' of events that are less than, say, 60 s from the earlier event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is code using `dplyr`.

First, it sorts by `time` just in case they are out of order. Then, it calculates a `timeChange` using `difftime` to ensure it returns in seconds and determines if it `isBigChange` (here, greater than 60 seconds). Then, it uses each `TRUE` to increment the group number using `cumsum` (counts each `TRUE` as a 1). It then `group_by`s that `group`, and calculates the summaries you wanted.

```
df %>%
  arrange(time) %>%
  mutate(timeChange = difftime(time, lag(time, default = time[1])
                               , units = "secs")
         , isBigChange = timeChange > 60
         , group = cumsum(isBigChange)) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarise(
    start = min(time)
    , end = max(time)
    , count = n()
  )
```

Returns

```
  group               start                 end count
  <int>              <dttm>              <dttm> <int>
1     0 2016-10-28 19:21:19 2016-10-28 19:21:21     4
2     1 2016-10-28 19:23:23 2016-10-28 19:23:25     4
3     2 2016-10-30 03:59:09 2016-10-30 03:59:09     1
4     3 2016-10-30 08:54:31 2016-10-30 08:54:35     2
```

Comment: Fyi, OP uses 60 sec in their current example. Here's the data.table analogue of this answer: `df[order(time), .(start = time[1L], end = time[.N], count = .N), by=.(group = cumsum(time - shift(time, fill = time[1L]) > 60))]`

Comment: Thanks @Frank, I hadn't seen the time threshold added from the edit.