# R Creating a time-varying survival dataset from event data

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, lubridate, survival-analysis

I want to create a survival dataset featuring multiple-record ids. The existing event data consists of one row observations with the date formatted as `dd/mm/yy`. The idea is to count the number of consecutive months where there is at least one event/month (there are multiple years, so this has to be accounted for somehow). In other words, I want to create *episodes* that capture such monthly streaks, including periods of inactivity. To give an example, the code should transform something like this:

```
df1
id        event.date
group1    01/01/16
group1    05/02/16
group1    07/03/16
group1    10/06/16
group1    12/09/16
```

to this:

```
df2
id        t0    t1    ep.no   ep.t   ep.type
group1    1     3     1       3      1  
group1    4     5     2       2      0
group1    6     6     3       1      1
group1    7     8     4       2      0
group1    9     9     5       1      1
group1    10    ...   ...     ...    ...
```

where `t0` and `t1` are the start and end months, `ep.no` is the episode counter for the particular `id`, `ep.t` is the length of that particular episode, and `ep.type` indicates the type of episode (active/inactive). In the example above, there is an initial three-months of activity, then a two-month break, followed by a single-month episode of relapse etc.

I am mostly concerned about the transformation that brings about the `t0` and `t1` from `df1` to `df2`, as the other variables in `df2` can be constructed afterwards based on them (e.g. no is a counter, time is arithmetic, and type always starts out as 1 and alternates). Given the complexity of the problem (at least for me), I get the need to provide the actual data, but I am not sure if that is allowed? I will see what I can do if a mod chimes in.

Comment: Does this question work for you: http://stackoverflow.com/q/40344190/1480928

Comment: Thanks for the link, I thought it might come down to `lubridate`. I'll have to spend some time to confirm whether it can work for my problem, though (on it now).

Comment: Update: When I use the code provided in the accepted answer, I get a `df` that has one observation per group, which includes a count variable that captures how many consecutive events (within a 30-day span) have occurred belonging to that group. What I need is multiple episodes per group.

Answer (score 1):

I think this does what you want. The trick is identifying the sequence of observations that need to be treated together, and using `dplyr::lag` with `cumsum` is the way to go.

```
# Convert to date objects, summarize by month, insert missing months
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

# added rows of data to demonstrate that it works with 
# > id and > 1 event per month and rolls across year end
df1 <- read_table("id        event.date
group1    01/01/16
group1    02/01/16
group1    05/02/16
group1    07/03/16
group1    10/06/16
group1    12/09/16
group1    01/02/17
group2    01/01/16
group2    05/02/16
group2    07/03/16",col_types="cc")

# need to get rid of extra whitespace, but automatically converts to date
# summarize by month to count events per month
df1.1 <- mutate(df1, event.date=dmy(event.date),
              yr=year(event.date),
              mon=month(event.date))

# get down to one row per event and complete data
df2 <- group_by(df1.1,id,yr,mon) %>%
  summarize(events=n()) %>%
  complete(id, yr, mon=1:12, fill=list(events=0)) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(event = as.numeric(events >0),
    is_start=lag(event,default=-1)!=event,
    episode=cumsum(is_start), 
    episode.date=ymd(paste(yr,mon,1,sep="-"))) %>%
  group_by(id, episode) %>%
  summarize(t0 = first(episode.date),
            t1 = last(episode.date) %m+% months(1),
            ep.length = as.numeric((last(episode.date) %m+% months(1)) - first(episode.date)),
            ep.type = first(event))
```

Gives

```
Source: local data frame [10 x 6]
Groups: id [?]

       id episode         t0         t1 ep.length ep.type
    <chr>   <int>     <dttm>     <dttm>     <dbl>   <dbl>
1  group1       1 2016-01-01 2016-04-01        91       1
2  group1       2 2016-04-01 2016-06-01        61       0
3  group1       3 2016-06-01 2016-07-01        30       1
4  group1       4 2016-07-01 2016-09-01        62       0
5  group1       5 2016-09-01 2016-10-01        30       1
6  group1       6 2016-10-01 2017-02-01       123       0
7  group1       7 2017-02-01 2017-03-01        28       1
8  group1       8 2017-03-01 2018-01-01       306       0
9  group2       1 2016-01-01 2016-04-01        91       1
10 group2       2 2016-04-01 2017-01-01       275       0
```

Using `complete()` with `mon=1:12` will always make the last episode stretch to the end of that year. The solution would be to insert a `filter()` on yr and mon after `complete()`

The advantage of keeping t0 and t1 as Date-time objects is that they work correctly across year boundaries, which using month numbers won't.

Session information:

```
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets 
[6] methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] lubridate_1.3.3 dplyr_0.5.0     purrr_0.2.2    
[4] readr_0.2.2     tidyr_0.6.0     tibble_1.2     
[7] ggplot2_2.2.0   tidyverse_1.0.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.8      knitr_1.15.1     magrittr_1.5    
 [4] munsell_0.4.2    colorspace_1.2-6 R6_2.1.3        
 [7] stringr_1.1.0    highr_0.6        plyr_1.8.4      
[10] tools_3.3.2      grid_3.3.2       gtable_0.2.0    
[13] DBI_0.5          lazyeval_0.2.0   assertthat_0.1  
[16] digest_0.6.10    memoise_1.0.0    evaluate_0.10   
[19] stringi_1.1.2    scales_0.4.1
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch for giving it a shot. However, when I run your code, I get an error at the `summarize(events=n()) %>%` line saying argument by is missing - any ideas?

Comment: @rfsrc dplyr::summarize() doesn't have a by argument, so you have some other package loaded that is conflicting with `dplyr`

Comment: Okay, if I replace `ep.no = sum(events)` from your code to `ep.length = (last(episode.date) %m+% months(1)) - first(episode.date)`, it produces the duration of the episode in days (as in numerical). Doing so also takes care of the year-switching problem, as well as the ending up with a `lubridate::Period` object.

Comment: Finally, can you include the `filter()` bit you mentioned after complete to get rid of the last stretch? Also, while I agree that keeping `t0` and `t1` as date-objects is useful, the multistate survival model I'm planning to use might require those to be numeric (it is a clock-reset model).